# count blanks from the input

Tags: c, console

I wrote a program to count blanks. I can compile it and run it, it's fine. But why it does not display the count?

```
#include<stdio.h>
main()
{ 
    int count=0;
    int c;

    while((c=getchar())!=EOF)
    {  
        if(c == ' ') count++;
    }
    printf("%d\n",count);
}
```

Comment: main() is missing a return type. What platform? How are you running this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your exact code (errors and all) works as you'd expect at [ideone](http://ideone.com/gO6AW).

---

How do you terminate the input? To send an EOF signal to your program from the console type, at the beginning of a line, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> in Linux or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Z</kbd> in Windows.

---

Also try to run with redirected input. Something like

```
yourprog < data.txt
```

or

```
echo one two three four | yourprog
```

Answer (score 1):

You're probably not getting the EOF that you expect from input. You may be expecting the Enter key to be EOF, which will not happen. Have you tried using one of the ctrl+ combinations such as Z or D (depending on OS) to send the EOF ?